# Extracting realtime information from a website and putting it into an Windows Phone 7 app

Tags: c#, parsing, web-scraping, data-binding, windows-phone-7

My question is based in an area I am very new to, so I would appreciate some patience/pointers to useful resources if possible.

I have plans to write a series of Windows Phone applications. The general idea of these applications would be to extract info that is available on a website and put it onto the phone so that it is more streamlined etc.

This very idea is something I am completely new to. I have written programs to parse applications and xml files before, but never strip information from a website. As such I am completely lost.

To make this a less vague, and more solid question - let's take an example ; http://www.luas.ie/. You can see this website has a "Live Information" section where you can select your stop and find when the next tram is leaving.

Let's say I want to write a simple Windows Phone 7 application that will simply allow me to select a station, and then uses the same query that this website does to  find out when the next tram is leaving - all I want to do is extract, for example, "5 minutes" and print it to screen.

How would I go about doing this? What are some good resources to read to learn good practice here ?

Comment: Off topic, but have you checked the terms of use of those web sites?

Comment: @NicholasButler, no, this is another area I am wondering about - I figured SO wasn't the place to ask about legalities, however! :)

Comment: Absolutely - just wondered! I guess unless you are lucky and the website uses some sort of web service API, you'll have to scrape the site html, which is always brittle.

Comment: So does that essentially boil down to parsing the HTML using Regular Expressions (bleh!) and something like the HtmlAgilityPack? ( http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ ). I was hoping there would be a magical, nicer way that I have never heard of or seen before! :) As it is related, I'm guessing the terms of use is an issue and the website owner should always be asked for permission to harness their information ?

Comment: Yes to both. Your best bet might be to contact the websites and ask for support or maybe some sort of joint venture.

Comment: I see. Thanks very much for your responses. I'm wondering about third-party apps getting produced that provide functions similar to my example - some of them are quite awful - you'd have to assume that very few actually do ask for permission!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an API isn't available from the website in question and you have checked the [legal ramifications](http://www.galvanilegal.com/is-web-scraping-legal) of scraping their content - I tend to use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse HTML and scrape a webpage's content.

Comment: Very informative and something I have since used to make 3/4 apps. Sorry for the long time in accepting and responding! :)